# C# dllimport: Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#

I have this function in c++

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void SendPacketToServer(BYTE *packet, int Length)
{
    _SendToServer(packet, Length);
}
```

How can I use it in c#?

I tried this so far:

```
[DllImport("DAFramework 1.0.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern void SendPacketToServer(IntPtr packet, int length);

            unsafe 
            {
                fixed (byte* pByte = new byte[] { 0x13, 0x00 })
                {
                    IntPtr data = new IntPtr((void*)pByte);
                    SendPacketToServer(data, 2);
                }
            }
```

Am I doing something incorrect? If so, How can I make it work? I'm getting the error: `Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.`

can I do it a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

You must set appropriate calling convention:

```
[DllImport("DAFramework 1.0.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

because your native function declares it (`extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)`).

Answer (score 0):

I think its a similar problem, in my case was due to **char*** parameter. I think you have to allocate previously the parameter.

> So your only solution is to pass the string parameters as IntPtr.
> Allocate the memory with Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi

[Attempted to read or write protected memory with dllimport in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674616/attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-with-dllimport-in-c-sharp)